# Passing data to the initState function

Tags: flutter, dart, init, pass-data

The problem: I need to pass `data` to the function `moveCamera`. `Data` is the data which is downloaded from the firestore. The problem is that I don't call the `initState` function from another function, so I can't pass `data` to the `initState` fuction for passing it to the `_onScroll` function. Passing it from `_onScroll` to `moveCamera` is no problem. The question is how can I pass data to the `initState` function and from there to the `_onScroll` function.

The first part:

```
  void initState() {
    ctrl = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.8)
      ..addListener((_onScroll));
    _queryDB();
    }
```

The second part:

```
  void _onScroll(data) {
    if (ctrl.page.toInt() != prevPage) {
      prevPage = ctrl.page.toInt();
      moveCamera(data);
    }
  }
```

And the thirt part:

```
void moveCamera(data) {
    print(data);
    _controller.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(data['location-latitude'], data['location-longitude']),
          zoom: 14.0,
          bearing: 45.0,
          tilt: 45.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass it as an arguments to the StatefulWidget? You can then access it from the initState method of the State object using widget:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
    final var data;
    Foo(this.data);
    
    @override
    _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
    
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _somefunction(widget.data);
    }
}
```